# Lyapunov exponents for PDEs

Tags: dynamical-systems

How can one define and calculate (analytically or numerically) Lyapunov exponents for partial differential equations? Do there exist examples of nonlinear PDEs for which Lyapunov exponents can be calculated analytically?